# VBA - Do While loop nested in a For Loop; Application-defined or object-defined errror

Tags: vba, excel

**Aim:**

So I'm brand new to VBA and was working on a quick script which tries to record the hours of work done in a week.

It does this by copying the numbers of hours of work done per day for each day contained in row 27 from column B (Monday) to column G (Saturday) in the `This Week` sheet and pastes that infomation in the `Hours` sheet starting at column B and working along to column G.

I want to do this so that I can keep a permanent record of the hours done even after I've changed my `This week` sheet schedule for the next week.

So I've tried to write this script so that if it sees the row above full of infomation it tries the row below.

This would result in a permanent, chronological (every week starts a new row) record of how many hours done per day every week.

I'd run this at the end of the week before clearing the schedule for the next week.

**Code:**

```
Sub Hours()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim hoursdone As Long

j = 0
For i = 2 To 7
    hoursdone = Worksheets("This Week").Cells(27, i).Value
    Do While Worksheets("Hours").Cells(j, i).Value <> Empty
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    Worksheets("Hours").Cells(i, j) = hoursdone
    Next i

End Sub
```

The Error I keep getting:

```
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

When I click `Debug` it takes me to `Line 9` and I've no idea what's gone wrong?

Thanks

PS: I want to eventually tie this thing to a button within my `This week` sheet to press, recording the data, allowing me to clear `This week`

Comment: **Do While Worksheets("Hours").Cells(j, i).Value <> ""**

Comment: Empty is a valid condition. Try `?activecell = empty` in the Immediate window.

Comment: It's a bit odd that you max out your rows at integer but allow someone to work **Long** hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be because `j` is starting out at the number `0`. You can not have `Cells(0, 2)`, rows start at the number 1.

Change the `j = 0` to `j = 1`, and also move that inside your `For...Next` statement.

```
For i = 2 To 7

    j = 1
    hoursdone = Worksheets("This Week").Cells(27, i).Value
    Do While Worksheets("Hours").Cells(j, i).Value <> Empty
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    Worksheets("Hours").Cells(i, j) = hoursdone
    Next i

End Sub
```

If you do not move the `j = 1` inside your For statement, then the next iteration j will be what is was where it left off from when it was inside your `Do...loop`.